# Representing two components of a variable using a barchart in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have employee data, that is ordered as below

```
  year status   exp  
   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> 
 1  2011 0      8.40   
 2  2011 1      6.66   
 3  2012 0      7.49   
 4  2012 1      5.78   
 5  2013 0      6.48   
 6  2013 1      4.51
```

For each year, the status can be 0 or 1; 0 is the average experience of people who have quit and 1 is the average experience of people who are staying.I would like to represent this data in a barchart, with year on the X axis and experience on y axis, with the stacked bar on the basis of status.

However,

Comment: Hi Ramesh, part of the question is missing. However, ....

Comment: Thank you.I have been doing on numeric data and running into trouble!

Answer (score 0):

Using ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(year), y = exp, fill = as.factor(status))) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(y = "experience", x = "Year", fill = "Status")
```

[image]

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L
), status = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), exp = c(8.4, 6.66, 7.49, 
5.78, 6.48, 4.51)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```